# How to determine storage key or descriptor of current user

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

A lot of the Azure DevOps APIs take a storage key as input when referencing a user.  That storage key is a unique identifier for the user in the organization in which you're working. I can't seem to figure out how to determine the storage key for the currently logged on user.

I know I can call the [Get Profile API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/profile/profiles/get?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1) and specify `Me` as the id, but that returns information about the current user in general - not as it relates to a specific organization.
The [List Users](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/graph/users/list?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1) api could to be used to a get a list of all the users in an organization but I'd rather not search through the results to get the signed-in user. And the [Get User](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/graph/users/get?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1) api requires a user descriptor and doesn't seem to allow me to specify `Me` to get the current user.
So how to I go about getting the storage key (or even descriptor) for the current user?

Comment: Hi, how's things going? Does the below work around is work for you? If you still facing any issue when getting the storage key/descriptor, feel free to leave comment there:-)

Answer (score 0):

The `descriptor` which get by [Get Profile API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/profile/profiles/get?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1), it just can represent the user self. In another word, it is the identity which would access the server `dev.azure.com`(not org, just identified by the server). So the `descriptor` got here could not used for Org because of could not identified in it.

Also, for the [Get User api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/graph/users/get?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1) and the [List User api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/graph/users/list?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1), they are all organization level which means its query result would be the one for entire org. And we did not offered the `filter` feature for Azure Devops rest api.

So, if want to `filter` by specify one user in API url, unfortunately to say, sorry, this does not supported while you using Azure Devops rest api. You must follow the restrict URL format shown in the doc.

---

As workaround, here you can use powershell script to achieve the filter.

You can execute the script in Azure devops pipeline:

```
$url = 'https://vssps.dev.azure.com/{org}/_apis/graph/users?api-version=5.0-preview.1';
$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Headers @{Authorization = "Bearer $env:SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN"} -Method Get
$results = $response.value | Where {$_.displayname -eq "{your account name}"} #|
Write-Host "results = $($results | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 100)"
Write-Host $results.desciptor
```

Or run it in Powershell ISE locally which would more convenient than the previous one:

[image]

Then you can store the `desciptor` into one parameter and use it in the [Storage Keys - Get API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/graph/storage%20keys/get?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1).

Comment: That's essentially the List Users API which forces me to filter the results for a specific user.  Not an ideal solution but I suppose it's workable if there are no other solutions.

Comment: @MikePearce Yes, you are right, this indeed is the approach to filter the list result because as I know we couldn’t provide such API can directly get the exactly one.

Comment: @MikePearce Another reason to filter result additionally is for azure devops rest api, we does not allow applying `filter` into API URI. So for exactly you want, here you need make script to achieve that.

Comment: @MikePearce. Does this answer could help for solve your puzzle? You can [accept the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if you think it would be help for other SO users who has the puzzle with you.

Answer (score 0):

The `connectionData` API endpoint might help you. It seems that Microsoft have forgotten to properly document it, but the object returned is documented through the azure-devops-extension-api JavaScript library at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/azure-devops-extension-api/connectiondata.

Here is an example for use with a Azure DevOps pipeline

```bash
$contentType = "application/json";
$headers = @{ Authorization = 'Bearer $(System.AccessToken)' };
$uri = "$(System.CollectionUri)/_apis/connectionData?api-version=7.0-preview.1";
$connectionData = Invoke-RestMethod -uri $uri -method GET -Headers $headers -ContentType $contentType
# The VSID a.k.a. Storage Key of the current user, E.g. "e2f6c43a-c231-4f82-841a-bfc82920ffaa"
$authorizedUserVSId = $connectionData.authorizedUser.id
# The "old" Identity Descriptor, e.g. "Microsoft.IdentityModel.Claims.ClaimsIdentity;9e57a836-f042-42ae-83bd-49f609cbd058\user@example.com"
$authorizedUserIdentityDescriptor = $connectionData.authorizedUser.descriptor
# The "new" Graph User Descriptor a.k.a Subject Descriptor. E.g. "aad.ZTJmNmM0M2EtYzIzMS00ZjgyLTg0MWEtYmZjODI5MjBmZmFh"
$authorizedUserSubjectDescriptor = $connectionData.authorizedUser.subjectDescriptor
```